# Keep a Sub running afterworkbook is closed

Tags: excel, vba

From my add-in file named "myAddIn.xlam" I run the follwoing sub

```
sub fisrtSub()

    'I use any variable name so I can call application.run
    anything = Application.Run("FileOfSecondSub.xlsm!secondSub",arg1,arg2)

end dub
```

So vba goes to secondSub on the workbook named "FileOfSecondSub.xlsm"

```
sub secondSub()

    Workbooks("myAddIn.xlam").Close
    msgbox "Success"

end sub
```

After closing my add-in workbook VBA stop the execution of the code without showing any message, I ve tried to using error handler techniques but the code still stops just after I close my add-in file. Is it possible to keep the sub running after I close the add-in file (the first file that started running the subs)?

And no, I can't close the workbook myAddIn.xlam latter on the code since I need to close it to replace myAddIn.xlam for a new one.

Comment: If you are trying to update an add-in for multiple users, please see: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment

Comment: Using the method above I am still not able to save the file. Excels display a message warning that file cannot be saved because is already in use.

Comment: Did you save it as read-only?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it won't work because you're essentially cutting the head off your code.  When you close the file that kicked off your process ("parent"), the code will terminate.  If you need additional code to run after the "parent" workbook is closed, try writing that piece into a VBScript file.  Then, call the script just prior to closing the "parent" file.

Comment: That could work, but is it possible to passa parameters to a VBScript just like I would do when calling a sub with parameters?

Comment: Yes. You would Shell the script and follow the .vbs file path with the parameters you need to pass.  `Shell(FilePath & " " & param1 " " & param2, vbNormalFocus)`. Then within your VBScript file you would retrieve arguments passed by using WScript.Arguments (this will return an array),  `Set params = WScript.Arguments`